# Mule - how to upload multiple files to FTP using quartz

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

I was wondering how I could upload multiple files on a given interval using `quartz` to FTP. I've already checked out this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478401/how-to-schedule-a-service-using-quartz-component-that-will-invoke-a-file-uploade), but unfortunately the upload job processes only one file at time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you are referring to, I take it that you really mean "how to read multiple files using Quartz". If you need to use Quartz to schedule reading all the files in a directory, you can not use a simple file endpoint polling job. Depending on your use case, one option would be to use Quartz to periodically start and stop a file connector or a flow with a file inbound. See [this example](http://ivankrizsan.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/schedule-reading-of-multiple-files-with-mule/) get an idea of how this would work. Another option would be to run shell commands from Mule, or just do the whole thing with cron&shell and skip Mule completely.

Regarding the original phrasing of your question, Mule FTP does not support sending multiple files at the same time (ftp mput), in case you would want to do that.