# Mule HTTPS File Upload

Tags: post, https, mule

I am trying to create a RESTful service within Mule using a File connector as an inbound endpoint, when a file is present this should then be pushed to an HTTPS endpoint. Using the question below as a starting point I have tried to follow this method. There are no exceptions returned and the file does not transfer.

[How to upload multiple files via REST over HTTP using Mule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457455/how-to-upload-multiple-files-via-rest-over-http-using-mule)

Within this question there was a comment regarding the content type not being set, i had the same issue but for the purposes of my testing i have tried to push a text file through.

```html
    <file:connector name="File" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS">
        <https:tls-key-store path="keystore.jks" keyPassword="PASS" storePassword="PASS"/>
        <https:tls-server path="nr_up_truststore.ts" storePassword="PASS"/>
    </https:connector>
    <flow name="Flow1" doc:name="Flow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="Path" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File" disableTransportTransformer="true">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="file(.*).txt" caseSensitive="false"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <object-to-byte-array-transformer encoding="ISO-8859-5" doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>
        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="host" port="443"  method="POST"   doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" path="PATH" mimeType="text/plain" password="PASS" user="USER"/>
    </flow>
```

With following exception stack

Exception stack is:
1. No trusted certificate found (sun.security.validator.ValidatorException)
  sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator:-1 (null)
2. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException)
  sun.security.ssl.Alerts:-1 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLHandshakeException.html)
3. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://:@URL, connector-HttpsConnector

Comment: could you set the debugging level of org.apache.http.wire to debug and share the results?

Comment: Updated to show no trusted certificate stack

Comment: In order to try create an SSL connection i first created a keytool, then exported to a client store certificate and finally created a truststore using the client cert.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the certificate set up in your local keychain.

The command line tools are very difficult and TLS/SSL is a complex matter. I do suggest you use a graphical tool like [key store explorer](http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/) to download the certificate of the site and create a java keystore with it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i have attempted to create a keystore this way and imported the SSL cert from the site i am now receive the following stack                Exception stack is:
1. No X509TrustManager implementation available (java.security.cert.CertificateException)
  sun.security.ssl.DummyX509TrustManager:-1 (null)
2. java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException)
  sun.security.ssl.Alerts:-1 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLHandshakeException.html)